# Joomla 1.6 template

Tags: php, joomla

I created a custom template in Joomla 1.6. It is located in the templates folder. However, I am not able to assign it and see any changes for it on the site.

Why are the template changes in index.php not showing up in the styles

Answer (score 1):

These are 2 different questions. Regarding why you can't assign it, it could be an error in the template's XML file.

As far as the changes aren't showing up, well if you can't assign it, you've answered your own question, haven't you?

Can you better clarify your question?

Comment: see...1> I have created a custom template called Example under the joomla/templates path. I have updated all of the details for a new template as i did in Joomla 1.5 but in joomla 1.5 if I would hit refresh, any changes in the templateDetails.xml would show up in the template listing.   However in Joomla1.6 there is styles and templates, Why are the changes that I make in the templateDetails.xml not making the corresponding changes in the styles list.  Basically can you please tell me how to make changes in the styles list / templates ?  I hope you got a clarification

Answer (score 0):

Might be a a daft question, but have youselected that template in the back end admin area of the joomla install? also you must set the desired template to default also.